# Restricting number of rows

Tags: database, constraints

I want to restrict the maximum possible rows that can be inserted in the table. Is it possible to have such constraint in database ?

Comment: Firstly, what database system are you using?

Comment: Do you want to restrict the size of the table? (the number of rows)
or do you want to restrict the number of rows inserted at any one time?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your DB system, you may use triggers to do this. It could count the number of records on each insert (or significantly better, cache it on insert and delete) and just reject it when it reaches a certain number.

But to me, this sounds like a very strange requirement. It would certainly be reasonably counter-intuitive (to me, anyway). Perhaps you might wish to 'archive' when a certain number has been reached, or perform some complex task. But this would be better (significantly better) done as a background task (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using? If it a BEFORE INSERT Trigger you can do so. Also, some databases offer extensibility.

[Oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) support them for sure, not sure about SQL Server. In the trigger, you could call a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE and then cancel if the limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

SQL constraints typically limit a type of insertion or a duplication, but not the *amount* of information being inserted.

You should be able to limit inserts from the client doing the inserting, though. On the SQL side, you could use a trigger to prevent insertion if the number of records exceeds a given amount.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a business rule that could change over time, I would not put the code in the database at all, but in the layer above that is calling it.

At that point you would have your business layer validate to see if the rule as been met prior to doing the insert.